# Unrecognized Data Type Sequelize Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Working on a small project where I need to populate a postgres database based on some log data. I've decided to use Sequelize to create my model and db connection.

When trying to call SignalDegs.create() to insert a record I receive the below error message. I've tried to reference DataTypes and import it instead of Sequalize directly resulting in the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!.

Error:

```
throw new Error(`Unrecognized datatype for attribute "${this.name}.${name}"`);
        ^
Error: Unrecognized datatype for attribute
```

Model File:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database/index.js');

const SignalDefs = db.define(
  'signaldefs',
  {
    signalType: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    messageSource: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    messageName: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    signalName: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    unit: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    signalID: { autoIncrement: true }
  },
  { freezeTableName: true }
);

const FloatSignals = db.define(
  'floatsignals',
  {
    floatValue: { type: Sequelize.FLOAT },
    time: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.DATE },
    vehicleID: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    signal: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER }
  },
  { freezeTableName: true }
);

module.exports = { SignalDefs, FloatSignals };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't set a type for the signalID field
2. Are you sure you want almost all fields of the signaldefs model to participate in primary key?

Comment: I am a bufoon thank you, I personally wouldn't ask all the fields to participate but its a requirement. Thanks again.